# Tiled background: Not all sprites appear

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, tile, skspritenode, sknode

I am trying to create a scene that will have a tiled background on top of which there will exist the available levels the user can select and he/she will be able to pan the background in order to view all the levels.

So, as was suggested in the iOS Games by Tutorials I created a `SKNode *_backgroundLayer` that would hold all the tiles as well as anything else that would go on top. This would allow me to just move the `SKNode` around and all its children would move with it. Great. Now, my tiles are `450x450 pixels` so I calculated that I would need 9 tiles in my `_backgroundLayer` and I used the code below to add them.

What I don't understand is this: It loads and positions the first two tiles that have to appear in my screen and it doesn't seem to load the rest! In the "x nodes" in the simulator it says that it has 2 nodes, instead of 9. Does it create the nodes and then removes them because they are not inside the my iphone screen initially? I don't get it. Any ideas on how to go about this and solve it?

UPDATE: In my iPad Retina I get 6 nodes instead of 9 so why is it only loading and keeping the nodes that can be shown in the screen and not all of them as I request in the code below?

UPDATE2: NSLog(@"%d", _backgroundLayer.children.count); does return 9 as it should. I am quite certain I am doing somethings wrong with the UIPanGestureRecognizer. Am I moving the wrong layer?

```
#import "LevelSelectScene.h"
#import "TurtleWorldSubScene.h"

@interface LevelSelectScene ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) SKSpriteNode *selectedNode;
@end

@implementation LevelSelectScene
{
    SKNode *_backgroundLayer;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

        _backgroundLayer = [SKNode node];
        _backgroundLayer.name = @"backgroundLayer";
        [self addChild:_backgroundLayer];

        SKTexture *backgroundTexture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"levelSelect"];
        int textureID = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {

                SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:backgroundTexture];

                background.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
                background.position = CGPointMake((background.size.width)*i, (background.size.height)*j);
                background.zPosition = 0;
                background.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"background%d", textureID];

                NSLog(@"x:%f, y:%f", background.position.x, background.position.y);

                textureID++;

                [_backgroundLayer addChild:background];
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"%d", _backgroundLayer.children.count);

        //[TurtleWorldSubScene displayTurtleWorld:self];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

    }

}
@end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. The number of nodes count in the debug labels refers to the number of nodes drawn, not the total number in the scene graph. Check `_backgroundLayer.children.count` for the actual number of nodes.

Comment: But why then when I pan the background layer I don't see the rest of the sprites? Shouldn't the background layer (sknode) be something like 1500x1500 pixels since it has all these 9 sprites? I see a black background instead of another background sprite. Am I doing something wrong with the panning perhaps? But I pan the background layer.. I will upload the code to that as well. Any ideas? Btw, thanks for the reply!

Comment: what does _backgroundLayer.children.count return? If it returns 9 then perhaps for some reason the nodes simply aren't drawn (at the right position). Check properties: position, zPosition, hidden, anchorPoint, xScale, yScale, frame and size for anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: UPDATE2: NSLog(@"%d", _backgroundLayer.children.count); does return 9 as it should. I am quite certain I am doing somethings wrong with the UIPanGestureRecognizer. Am I moving the wrong layer?

Comment: Maybe you are moving the layer in the wrong direction? If you pan from left to right the translation will be positive but maybe you want to move the backgroundLayer node in the opposite direction so that panning from left to right actually moves the background towards the left.